# How do I debug `perf`'s "Permission error mapping pages." when running `perf` on multiple processes in parallel?

Tags: perf

`perf` sometimes gives me

```
Permission error mapping pages.
Consider increasing /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_mlock_kb,
or try again with a smaller value of -m/--mmap_pages.
(current value: 4294967295,0)
```

when I run `perf record` on multiple processes at the same time (e.g., via `make -j2`).  A complete transcript can be found, for example, [here](https://github.com/mit-plv/fiat-crypto/runs/6080523704?check_suite_focus=true#step:8:6240).

The failing command has a peak memory usage of 9944 ko (according to `command time -f "%M ko"`), there was another command running at the same time with peak memory usage of 131984 ko.

Is there a known issue with running `perf` on multiple processes at the same time?  This doesn't seem like an OOM issue.  How do I debug this?